# Linear regression between dependent variable with multiple independent variables

Tags: r, linear-regression

I would like to create a function where the dependent variable (y) regressed with individual independent variables (x1, x2, etc.) but not in the form of multiple regression. And I would like to include another function in the same formula is to calculate AIC value. So, both of these functions in the same formula. Can somebody have any idea how to do it? I have a huge dataset and I need to find a regression for an individual dependent variable with multiple independent variables. I would really appreciate it if somebody guides me here.

Comment: If more than one variable is related to the response, you will be very likely to have [*omitted variable bias*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted_variable_bias) in each of the simple-regressions.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give you the results of the dependent variable (y) regressed with individual independent variables

```r
data(mtcars)

x = names(mtcars[,-1])
out <- unlist(lapply(1, function(n) combn(x, 1, FUN=function(row) paste0("mpg ~ ", paste0(row, collapse = "+")))))
out
#>  [1] "mpg ~ cyl"  "mpg ~ disp" "mpg ~ hp"   "mpg ~ drat" "mpg ~ wt"  
#>  [6] "mpg ~ qsec" "mpg ~ vs"   "mpg ~ am"   "mpg ~ gear" "mpg ~ carb"
library(broom)
#> Warning: package 'broom' was built under R version 3.5.3
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

#To have the regression coefficients
tmp1 = bind_rows(lapply(out, function(frml) {
  a = tidy(lm(frml, data=mtcars))
  a$frml = frml
  return(a)
}))
head(tmp1)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#>   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value frml      
#>   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>     
#> 1 (Intercept)  37.9      2.07        18.3  8.37e-18 mpg ~ cyl 
#> 2 cyl          -2.88     0.322       -8.92 6.11e-10 mpg ~ cyl 
#> 3 (Intercept)  29.6      1.23        24.1  3.58e-21 mpg ~ disp
#> 4 disp         -0.0412   0.00471     -8.75 9.38e-10 mpg ~ disp
#> 5 (Intercept)  30.1      1.63        18.4  6.64e-18 mpg ~ hp  
#> 6 hp           -0.0682   0.0101      -6.74 1.79e- 7 mpg ~ hp

#To have the regression results i.e. R2, AIC, BIC
tmp2 = bind_rows(lapply(out, function(frml) {
  a = glance(lm(frml, data=mtcars))
  a$frml = frml
  return(a)
}))
head(tmp2)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 12
#>   r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic  p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC
#>       <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <int>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0.726         0.717  3.21     79.6  6.11e-10     2  -81.7  169.  174.
#> 2     0.718         0.709  3.25     76.5  9.38e-10     2  -82.1  170.  175.
#> 3     0.602         0.589  3.86     45.5  1.79e- 7     2  -87.6  181.  186.
#> 4     0.464         0.446  4.49     26.0  1.78e- 5     2  -92.4  191.  195.
#> 5     0.753         0.745  3.05     91.4  1.29e-10     2  -80.0  166.  170.
#> 6     0.175         0.148  5.56      6.38 1.71e- 2     2  -99.3  205.  209.
#> # ... with 3 more variables: deviance <dbl>, df.residual <int>, frml <chr>

write.csv(tmp1, "Try_lm_coefficients.csv")
write.csv(tmp2, "Try_lm_results.csv")
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The results can be found in "Try_lm_coefficients.csv" and "Try_lm_results.csv" files.